# iOS does not properly size a dynamic tableview controller in a container

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, containers

I'm experimenting with a tableview controller embedded within a container. I'm using dynamic prototypes for the table cells. The storyboard shows the correct size, however, when testing the tableview extends itself to the bottom of the screen obscuring the segmented buttons etc.

Just using standard code, nothing out of the ordinary, to initialize the table.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.topics.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TopicPrototypeCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Help us to help you by providing some code, thank you

Comment: If your using storyboards checkout which auto-constraints are set.  Try re-setting the auto-constraints.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the table is rendering views outside of the bounds you were expecting, you could check that your Container View has its 'Clip Subviews' option turned on. For this option look in the 'View' section of the Attributes Inspector in Interface Builder.

This could also be a problem with your layout constraints, but it's hard to tell without more information.

Additionally, I think it's worth noting that you don't need a Container to have a table inside of a scene. Instead of including a TableViewController scene with a container, you can just add a UITableView directly into your scene (just make sure to hook up your controller as the delegate and datasource).

Comment: I'll give that a try. But -- fiddling around I found the answer -- nothing is wrong! Turns out that the initial storyboards are sized for something greater than a 3.5 inch iPhone, which the simulator used by default. When you size the storyboard for the correct size what was hidden was there all along.